# How to make these parameters to show their value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I got a problem. This is my web application that i am working on and one of it's function is to get some data about minerals and store it in the localstore of the chrome. The problem is that some of the parameters do not show their value that were introduced by the user. This is what i obtain in the application section of the localstorage: `{"Name":"Calciu","Formula":"Ca","Class":null,"Price":"3","Currency":"RON","Units":"Grams","Quantity":"3","Dated":{"Date":null},"Details":null}` . Where you see null, there should be some values. I guarantee that i introduced in the forms all the values that were required. Down bellow is the code( there are some lines of code that are commented because i tried some features). I need help from you to get the values of those parameters that show null.

#add-mineral.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, NgModel, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ButtonRadioDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/buttons';
import { TabsetComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { IMineralBase } from 'src/app/model/imineralbase';
import { Mineral } from 'src/app/model/mineral';
import { MineralWorldService } from 'src/app/services/mineral-world.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-mineral',
  templateUrl: './add-mineral.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-mineral.component.scss']
})
export class AddMineralComponent implements OnInit {

 // @ViewChild ('Form') addMineralForm!: NgForm
  @ViewChild('formTabs') formTabs!: TabsetComponent;

  addMineralForm!: FormGroup;
  nextClicked_Name!: boolean;
  nextClicked_Price!: boolean;
  nextClicked_Quantity!: boolean;
  nextClicked!: boolean;
  mineral = new Mineral();

  classMinerals: Array<string> = ['Silicates','Sulfides','Carbonates','Oxides','Halides','Sulfates','Phosphates','Native Elements']
  currency: Array<string> = ['RON','USD','EUR']
  units: Array<string> = ['Grams','Kilograms','Pounds']

   mineralView: IMineralBase = {
      id: null as any,
      Name: '',
      Formula: '',
      Price: '',
      Currency: '',
      Quantity: '',
      Units: '',
      BuySell: null as any,
      Class : '',
      Dated: '',
      Details:''
   };

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private router: Router, private MineralWorldService: MineralWorldService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.CreateAddMineralForm();
  }

    CreateAddMineralForm(){
      this.addMineralForm = this.fb.group({
        BasicDetails: this.fb.group({
            Name: [null, Validators.required],
            Formula: [null, Validators.required],
            Class: [null, Validators.required]

        }),
        PriceQuantityInfo: this.fb.group({
        Currency: [null, Validators.required],
        Price: [null, Validators.required],
        Units: [null, Validators.required],
        Quantity: [null, Validators.required]
        }),
        Dated: this.fb.group({
          Date: [null, Validators.required]
        }),
        Detailss: this.fb.group({
          Details: [null, Validators.required]
        })
      });
    }

   mapMineral():void {
     //this.mineral.id = this.id.value;
     this.mineral.Name = this.Name.value;
     this.mineral.Formula = this.Formula.value;
     this.mineral.Class = this.Class.value;
     this.mineral.Price = this.Price.value;
     this.mineral.Currency = this.Currency.value;
     this.mineral.Units = this.Units.value;
     this.mineral.Quantity = this.Quantity.value;
     this.mineral.Dated = this.Dated.value;
     this.mineral.Details = this.Details.value;
    // this.mineral.BuySell = this.BuySell.value;

   }


  onBack()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }

  onSubmit(Form: NgForm)
  {
    this.nextClicked =true;
    this.mapMineral();
    this.MineralWorldService.addMineral(this.mineral);
    // if(this.allTabsValid())
    // {
    //   console.log('Congrats, your mineral listed successfully on the website');
    //   console.log(this.addMineralForm)
    // }else {
    //   console.log('Please review the form and provide valid information');
    // }
    console.log(this.addMineralForm);

  }

  // allTabsValid():boolean {
  //   if(this.BasicDetails.invalid)
  //   {
  //     this.formTabs.tabs[0].active = true;
  //     return false;
  //   }
  //   if(this.PriceQuantityInfo.invalid)
  //   {
  //     this.formTabs.tabs[1].active = true;
  //     return false;
  //   }
  //   if(this.Dated.invalid)
  //   {
  //     this.formTabs.tabs[2].active = true;
  //     return false;
  //   }
  //   if(this.Details.invalid)
  //   {
  //     this.formTabs.tabs[3].active = true;
  //     return false;
  //   }
  //   return true;
  // }

  selectTab(NextTabId: number)
  {
    // this.nextClicked =true;
    // if (IsCurrentTabValid)
    // {
    //   this.nextClicked_Name = true;
    //   this.nextClicked_Price = true;
    //   this.nextClicked_Quantity = true;
    //   this.formTabs.tabs[NextTabId].active =true;
    // }
    this.formTabs.tabs[NextTabId].active =true;
  }
  //#region ( Getter Methods )
    //#region <FormGroups>
        get BasicDetails() {
          return this.addMineralForm.controls.BasicDetails as FormGroup;
        }
        get PriceQuantityInfo() {
          return this.addMineralForm.controls.PriceQuantityInfo as FormGroup;
        }
        get Dated() {
          return this.addMineralForm.controls.Dated as FormGroup;
        }
        get Detailss() {
          return this.addMineralForm.controls.Detailss as FormGroup;
        }
  //#endregion
    //#region <Form Controls>


        get Name() {
          return this.BasicDetails.controls.Name as FormControl;
        }
        get Formula() {
          return this.BasicDetails.controls.Formula as FormControl;
        }
        get Class() {
          return this.BasicDetails.controls.Class as FormControl;
        }
        get Currency() {
          return this.PriceQuantityInfo.controls.Currency as FormControl;
        }
        get Price() {
          return this.PriceQuantityInfo.controls.Price as FormControl;
        }
        get Quantity() {
            return this.PriceQuantityInfo.controls.Quantity as FormControl;
        }

        get Units() {
          return this.PriceQuantityInfo.controls.Units as FormControl;
        }

        get Date() {
          return this.Dated.controls.Date as FormControl;
        }

        get Details() {
          return this.Detailss.controls.Details as FormControl;
        }
//#endregion
//#endregion
}
```

#add-mineral.component.html

```
<div class = "row mb-5">
 <div class = "col-9 shadow-lg p-0 bg-white">
<div class="card">
    <div class = "card-header">
       <h3>Sell a Mineral</h3>
    </div>
    <div class = "card-body" >
       <form (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'  [formGroup]="addMineralForm">
        <!-- [formGroup]="addMineralForm" -->
        <div class = "tab-panel">
           <tabset class = "member-tabset"  #formTabs>
              <tab heading = "Basic Details" formGroupName="BasicDetails">
                <div class = "form-group col-12"  >
                  <label for = "name">Name</label>
                  <input type = "text" class = "form-control" formControlName = "Name"  ngModel [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Name" >
                  <div class ="error-block" *ngIf = "Name.invalid && (nextClicked_Name || Name.touched)">Please add the name of the mineral</div>
              </div>
              <div class = "form-group col-12">
                <label for = "formula">Formula</label>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" ngModel  formControlName="Formula" [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Formula" >
            </div>
          <div class = "form-group col-12">
            <p>Class of Minerals</p>
            <div class = "btn-group" btnRadioGroup ngModel [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Class" name = "class" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
              <label *ngFor ="let cm of classMinerals"
              class = "btn btn-outline-dark text-central"
              [btnRadio]="cm" tabindex="0" role="button" name = "class"> {{cm}}
              </label>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class = "form-group col-12">
           <button type = "button"    class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" [disabled]="!Name.valid" (click)="selectTab(1)" >Next</button>
        </div>
              </tab>
              <tab heading = "Price and Quantity" formGroupName="PriceQuantityInfo" >
                <div class = "form-group col-12">
                   <p>Currency</p>
                   <div class = "btn-group" btnRadioGroup ngModel [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Currency" formControlName = "Currency" >
                     <label *ngFor ="let c of currency"
                     class = "btn btn-outline-dark mr-2"
                     [btnRadio]="c" tabindex="0" role="button" name = "Currency"> {{c}}
                     </label>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group col-12">
                  <label for = "price">Price</label>
                  <input type = "text" class = "form-control" ngModel formControlName = "Price" [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Price" >
                  <div class ="error-block" *ngIf = "Price.invalid && (nextClicked_Price || Price.touched)">Please add the price of the mineral</div>
              </div>
              <div class = "form-group col-12">
                <p>Units of Mass</p>
                <div class = "btn-group" btnRadioGroup [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Units" formControlName = "Units" >
                  <label *ngFor ="let m of units"
                  class = "btn btn-outline-dark mr-2"
                  [btnRadio]="m" tabindex="0" role="button" name = "Units"> {{m}}
                  </label>
                </div>
             </div>
              <div class = "form-group col-12">
                <label for = "quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" ngModel formControlName = "Quantity" [(ngModel)] = "mineralView.Quantity">
                <div class ="error-block" *ngIf = "Quantity.invalid && (nextClicked_Quantity || Quantity.touched)">Please add mineral quantity</div>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group col-12">
              <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" [disabled]="!Price.valid && !Quantity.valid" (click)="selectTab(2)" >Next</button>
              <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" (click)="selectTab(0)" >Back</button>
           </div>
              </tab>
              <tab heading = "Dated from" >
                <div class = "form-group col-12"  >
                  <label for = "date">Possession/Avaialble from (DD/MM/YYYY)</label>
                  <input type = "text" placeholder = "Datepicker"  ngModel [(ngModel)]="mineralView.Dated" name="date" class = "form-control"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue', dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}">
              </div>
                <div class = "form-group col-12">
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" (click)="selectTab(3)">Next</button>
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" (click)="selectTab(1)">Back</button>
               </div>
              </tab>

              <tab heading = "Other Details">
                <div class = "form-group col-12">
                  <label for = "details">Describe any details that may be useful</label>
                  <input type = "text" class = "form-control" ngModel [(ngModel)]="mineralView.Details" name = "OtherDetails" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
              </div>
                <div class = "form-group col-12">
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" (click)="selectTab(4)">Next</button>
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" (click)="selectTab(2)">Back</button>
               </div>
              </tab>
              <tab heading = "Images" >
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <div class="photo-control">
                      <button class="mt-5" type="button">Upload</button> <br>
                      This is under construction
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "form-group col-12">
                  <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" (click)="selectTab(3)">Back</button>
                  <button type = "reset" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" >Cancel</button>
                  <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-dark btn-block" >Save</button>
               </div>
              </tab>
           </tabset>
        </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class = "col-3 mr-auto">
    <div class = "card-header ">
    <h4 class = "text-white">Your Offer Preview</h4>
    </div>
     <div class = "shadow-lg p-3 bg-white ">
        <app-mineral-card [mineral]="mineralView" [hideIcons] = "true"></app-mineral-card>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you intended to put two 's' in this ? ```Detailss: this.fb.group...```

Comment: yes because otherwise i get this ``` Duplicate identifier 'Details'.```